# Automate the insertion of XML data into a database

Tags: php, xml, database

I made a script to automatically insert the XML data into a database, and I put it in a PHP file called `xml_to_database.php`.

Is there a way to automate the execution of the task (when the XML is updated or from time to time), instead of always putting the link in a browser (like entering `http://mysite/xml_to_database.php`)?

Comment: you can set cron for xml_to_database.php file.

Comment: I dint remember cron job, let me check it out.

Comment: Cron is often used when another solution could be more elegant. For instance, suppose you also have control over the process that changes your XML, then you could easily call "xml_to_database.php" from there whenever there's a change.